# Show another page of information based on the users reaction to a message (discord.py)

Tags: python, arrays, discord.py

I have a bot that has a command "!ShowInventory", which will show the players inventory, and the bot will react to the inventory message

```
msg = await ctx.send(toSend)
await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
await msg.add_reaction("➡️")
```

To get `toSend`...

Step 1: Split the array `player.Inventory` into several smaller arrays like this

```
y = list(chunks(player.Inventory, 4))


def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return (l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))
```

The out put for that looks something like this

```
Array = [array[items, moreitems, moreitems, moreitems,], array[etc, etc, etc, etc]]
```

Note: player.Inventory is an array (`Inventory = []`) in a seperate class (`player`)

Step 2:
Now that my new array looks like `y = [array[items, moreitems, moreitems, moreitems,], array[etc, etc, etc, etc]]`, I get the items from the sub-arrays like this

```
for x in list(y[pageNumber - 1]):
        toSend += x + "\n"
```

(-1 because the first page is stored at index 0 not index 1)

So now toSend is a string that looks like

```
Items
Items
Items
etc
```

QUESTION: I would like to know how I can

1. Check when the user reacted to the message
2. Do something based on the emoji they reacted too

e.g: If they reacted with "⬅️" the bot will send a new message with the previous pages items and if they react with "➡️" it will send a new message with the next pages items. I would also like this to be a loop, so that the user can then repeat this process of reacting to get to the previous/next page

This is a lengthy question and if you need any clarification, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `wait_for`

```py
msg = await ctx.send(toSend)
await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda r, u: r.message.id == msg.id)
if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅️":
    # previous page
elif str(reaction.emoji) == "➡️":
    # next page
```